# How do you get the amount of used bandwidth from a network interface and store it in a variable?

Tags: linux, networking, bash

I installed iftop and I would like to get the total value on to a variable as a example:

```
iftop -i mydevice 

                12.5Kb          25.0Kb          37.5Kb          50.0Kb    62.5Kb
└───────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────
sip                        => 188.241.227.198             2.53Kb  1.27Kb  1.27Kb
                           <=                            2.63Kb  1.31Kb  1.31Kb
















────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
TX:             cum:    648B    peak:   2.53Kb  rates:   2.53Kb  1.27Kb  1.27Kb
RX:                     673B            2.62Kb           2.63Kb  1.31Kb  1.31Kb
TOTAL:                 1.29KB           5.16Kb           5.16Kb  2.58Kb  2.58Kb
```

well i could put it here as text yes ! but i did

```
nohup iftop -i enp0s26y7a6 > iftop_output.txt &
```

When I use `cat` the file shows what I saved but when I open the file with `nano`, it displays a lot of code that I don't understand. I tried searching for the "TOTAL" amount on that code, but don't know how could I get put that amount into a variable.

Comment: What are you planning in using this for? I ask because there are fairly straight forward ways of byte counting in iptables which may -or may not - be a better alternative.

Comment: i just need put the total amount of the used bandwidth in to a variable from an specific network device, in that server i use  firewalld can't change

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did installing `vnstat` and use the same process, I explain:

vnstat it is a daemon which it is storing the usage on the network all the time and it is very complete in there query's example I'm interested in know the total amount of used bandwidth an a specific interface let's called mydevice after you install vnstat an start it you run after a wile, vnstat it is storing data !

```
vnstat -i mydevice  

Database updated: Wed Aug 19 11:38:48 2020

   mydevice since 08/18/2020

          rx:  9.63 MiB      tx:  6.73 MiB      total:  16.37 MiB

   monthly
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
       Aug '20      9.63 MiB |    6.73 MiB |   16.37 MiB |    0.08 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated        14 MiB |       9 MiB |      23 MiB |

   daily
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     yesterday      1.63 MiB |     873 KiB |    2.48 MiB |    0.24 kbit/s
         today      8.00 MiB |    5.88 MiB |   13.88 MiB |    2.71 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated        16 MiB |      10 MiB |      26 MiB |
```

then, there you have the TOTAL amount of used bandwidth at the given moment in the

```
estimated        16 MiB |      10 MiB |      26 MiB |
```

3rd column then i take it like

```
vnstat -i mydevice -d 2>&1 | grep estimated | cut -d '|' -f 3
```

and that's print

```
26 MiB
```

that's it, then you can do wherever you need or want whit it ! plus vnstat has a very interesting options to let you know the bandwidth by day by mount, I just installed but it is very good

```
 vnStat 1.15 by Teemu Toivola <tst at iki dot fi>

         -q,  --query          query database
         -h,  --hours          show hours
         -d,  --days           show days
         -m,  --months         show months
         -w,  --weeks          show weeks
         -t,  --top10          show top 10 days
         -s,  --short          use short output
         -u,  --update         update database
         -i,  --iface          select interface (default: eth0)
         -?,  --help           short help
         -v,  --version        show version
         -tr, --traffic        calculate traffic
         -ru, --rateunit       swap configured rate unit
         -l,  --live           show transfer rate in real time

See also "--longhelp" for complete options list and "man vnstat".
```

Answer (score 1):

All the necessary information is in the pseudo file `/proc/net/dev` that you can read/search in a script. For instance to get the counts for your ethernet interface (enpo-something) in a bash script:

```
read _ received _ _ _ _ _ _ _ transmitted _ < <(grep enp0 /proc/net/dev)
```

Comment: the command `read _ received _ _ _ _ _ _ _ transmitted _ < <(grep mydevice /proc/net/dev)` did not show anything but `grep mydevice /proc/net/dev` it does  something like this `mydevices: 452494256  488010   20    0    0    20          0         0 98146509  362934    0    0    0     0       0          0` i stick to vnstat for the moment

Comment: @Denn0n Of course it doesn't show anything since it stores the values in the `received` and `transmistted` variables, as per your question.

Comment: `lan=$(ifconfig | head -n 1 | sed -re 's/^([a-z0-9]+):.*/\1/') && read _ received _ _ _ _ _ _ _ transmitted _ < <(grep $lan /proc/net/dev) && echo $received $transmitted`

Comment: oh! okay but that's show's the current session right ? if you have to reboot or restart network's it will restart, of course it is one way to do so,  i did like it more vnstat  is not like it is wrong do it from the /proc/net/dev in fact it is more directly but since vnstat save it on a db it is pretty cool thank you all any way i will give a chance on some other time ;)

Comment: I assume vnstat is mostly storing away the data from /proc/net/dev...

Comment: @Hannu `ifconfig` is a bit deprecated these days (use `ip` instead) and the first  interface it lists on my system is the Docker bridge :)

Comment: Relax, it's just an example usage. Not a perfected script. :-) - most notably scribbled down in a minute or two. => to understand the principle. I think you could add some of the gist of it to your answer though.